# Error: [appCheck/token-error] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I have followed all steps for app-check implementation and it works properly in debug mode but not in production. It fails with the following error:

> **Error: [appCheck/token-error] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException:**
> **Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.**

I dont know if I am missing something or is this a bug? I have used this command to get the **SHA256**: `gradlew signingReport`

Here is how I initialize app-check and use it:

```
 const rnfbProvider = await firebaseAppCheck.newReactNativeFirebaseAppCheckProvider();
 await rnfbProvider.configure({
    android: {
       provider: __DEV__ ? 'debug' : 'playIntegrity',
       debugToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }
 });

 await firebaseAppCheck.initializeAppCheck({ provider: rnfbProvider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true })
    .then(async (res) => {
       const getToken = await firebaseAppCheck.getToken();
       ...          
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.error("app check failed: " + error);
    });
```